# How to take sqrt of float higher than 1090000006.0?

Tags: f#

I was trying to take the square root of a 19 digit number (1121314151617181910.0) and noticed that the "out-of-the-box" `Operators.sqrt` seemed to be failing. I'm fine writing the algorithm myself but was wondering if there was a different square root for large floats that I wasn't aware of and could leverage.

```
let testSqrt (square:float)= 
    let root = sqrt square
    (root * root) = square

testSqrt 1090000006.0 // true
testSqrt 1090000007.0 // false
```

Comment: You know about rounding error, right? That's why `(root * root) = square` isn't working for you. Note that `testSqrt 2.0` is **also** false! That's because `let root = sqrt 2.0; (root * root) - 2.0` is `4.440892099e-16`, due to rounding error. What you need is to be testing that `abs (square - root * root)` is less than a very small number, say `1.0e-6`.

Comment: Hasty post. Yes, I'm aware of rounding errors. Are you telling me there is no square root for 19 digit numbers?

Comment: `double` have "just" a 53 bit mantissa which gives ~16 decimals. You can implement a big rational type using `BigInteger` for arbitrary precision and then implement `sqrt` using Newton-Raphson. However as you know, many square roots end up as an irrational number which by definition can't be represented as a rational number thus you will never get an exact value for those situations. It's also possible to represent a result as an expression tree which is a about as exact you can get it I guess.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just large values that will fail your `testSqrt` function. Watch this:

```
let testSqrt (square:float)= 
    let root = sqrt square
    (root * root) = square

testSqrt 2.0 // false!
```

What's going on here is [rounding error](http://floating-point-gui.de/). When `sqrt` calculates the square root of 2, it gets an irrational number, but it has to store that number in a finite number of bits, so it rounds off at some point to produce `1.414213562`. Then when you multiply `1.414213562` by itself, you get a number that's very close to, but not exactly equal to, 2:

```
let root = sqrt 2.0
abs (2.0 - root * root) // 4.440892099e-16
```

To properly test `sqrt`, it's better to define some small value `epsilon` that will be larger than your expected rounding error, and check that the `root * root` value will be within `epsilon` of the right answer:

```
let epsilon = 1.0e-6
let testSqrt (square:float)= 
    let root = sqrt square
    abs (square - root * root) < epsilon
testSqrt 1090000006.0 // true
testSqrt 1090000007.0 // now this is also true
```

However, even that won't work with extremely large numbers, because the `float` type only has 64 bits of precision to work with, and at that rate, you're losing a LOT from rounding error:

```
let root = sqrt 1121314151617181910.0
1121314151617181910.0 - root * root // 128.0, WAY larger than epsilon
```

There's a `decimal` type in F# that will go to arbitrary precision, which you could use, though you'll have to implement `sqrt` yourself since it's not implemented for `decimal`:

```
let d = decimal 4  // Prints as 4M
let d' = 4M  // Another way to write "decimal 4"
sqrt d  // Error FS0001: The type 'decimal' does not support the operator 'Sqrt'
```

Beware: if you are using the `decimal` function to convert a float to decimal, you may still get rounding error if the number was too large to fully fit in a float:

```
let d = decimal 1121314151617181910.0  // 1121314151617180000M; float lost some precision
let d' = 1121314151617181910M  // Correct value, 1121314151617181910M
```

Comment: `decimal` isn't an arbitrary precision type it just has more precision and a smaller range than `float` and avoids round-off errors when doing, e.g. currency calculations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx#Anchor_6

Answer (score 3):

Floating point math is not exact. Simple values like 0.2 cannot be precisely represented using binary floating point numbers, and the limited precision of floating point numbers means that slight changes in the order of operations can change the result. Different compilers and CPU architectures store temporary results at different precisions, so results will differ depending on the details of your environment. If you do a calculation and then compare the results against some expected value it is highly unlikely that you will get exactly the result you intended.
That's why proper way of comparing float is something like that:

```
abs(result - expectedResult) < 0.00001
```